# Matrix multiplication using 1d arrays

Tags: c++, math, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to multiply two matrices stored inside 1d arrays.

I'm using this function, but my program crashes, I assume due to an out of bounds error.
However, I have no (easy) ability to debug, so I have to decide if my code is correct, and to me it seems it is...

```
void SampleUtils::multiplyMatrices(float* matA, int rA, int cA, float* matB,
        int rB, int cB, float* matC, int rC, int cC) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= rA; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= cB; j++) {
            float sum = 0.0;
            for (int k = 0; k <= rB; k++)
                sum = sum + matA[i * cA + k] * matB[k * cB + j];
            matC[i * cC + j] = sum;
        }

    }
```

So, can anyone find out what I did wrong?

Thanks...

Comment: If `rA` is the number of rows of the matrix, then the condition **must** be `i < rA`. Similarly at other places.

Comment: 1. Use a debugger to find out where it crashes. 2. Use vectors and call `at` to get an exception thrown if it is an out-of-bounds error.

Comment: "... to me it seems it is...." - the fact that your program crashes tells you that this statement is quite incorrect.  You'll find a solution faster if you start with the assumption that your code is wrong, and you're the one that made it so.

Comment: Isn't `rB` always equal to `cA`, and `rC` is not used? Generally, I think you need only three sizes (`ra=rC`, `rb=cA`, and `cb=cC`, if I remember it correctly), not six; consider eliminating the unused parameters to reduce the confusion.

Comment: @duffymo - yeah, I think it is incorrect. perhaps my English is off, but it was my way of saying: "I can't figure out what's the hell wrong with it" :-)

Also, sum should be a float obviously :-P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chances are you mean `<` instead of `<=` in your `for` loops.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use `i < rA` , `j < cB`, `k < rB` in your `for`