# multiplying numbers as a matrix

Tags: c++, c

Can someone tell me what is the best way to multiply a series of numbers as a matrix?

I mean.

I have seen algorithms for matrix multiplication, but are to multiply numbers as matrix1 [4] [4] and matrix2 [4] [4]. However, I want to multiply numbers as matrix1 [16] and matrix2 [16].

Is there any algorithm for this multiplication as fast as possible using float numbers?

Thank you very much for your help.

**EDIT**

I have used cBLAS and done some speed tests and I was surprised with the results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cblas.h>
#include  <GL/glfw.h>

    void matriz_matriz(float *matriz1,float *matriz2,float *matrizr){
      matrizr[0]  = (matriz1[0]*matriz2[0])+(matriz1[4]*matriz2[1])  +(matriz1[8]*matriz2[2])  +(matriz1[12]*matriz2[3]);
      matrizr[1]  = (matriz1[1]*matriz2[0])+(matriz1[5]*matriz2[1])  +(matriz1[9]*matriz2[2])  +(matriz1[13]*matriz2[3]);
      matrizr[2]  = (matriz1[2]*matriz2[0])+(matriz1[6]*matriz2[1])  +(matriz1[10]*matriz2[2]) +(matriz1[14]*matriz2[3]);
      matrizr[3]  = (matriz1[3]*matriz2[0])+(matriz1[7]*matriz2[1])  +(matriz1[11]*matriz2[2]) +(matriz1[15]*matriz2[3]);

      matrizr[4]  = (matriz1[0]*matriz2[4])+(matriz1[4]*matriz2[5])  +(matriz1[8]*matriz2[6])  +(matriz1[12]*matriz2[7]);
      matrizr[5]  = (matriz1[1]*matriz2[4])+(matriz1[5]*matriz2[5])  +(matriz1[9]*matriz2[6])  +(matriz1[13]*matriz2[7]);
      matrizr[6]  = (matriz1[2]*matriz2[4])+(matriz1[6]*matriz2[5])  +(matriz1[10]*matriz2[6]) +(matriz1[14]*matriz2[7]);
      matrizr[7]  = (matriz1[3]*matriz2[4])+(matriz1[7]*matriz2[5])  +(matriz1[11]*matriz2[6]) +(matriz1[15]*matriz2[7]);

      matrizr[8]  = (matriz1[0]*matriz2[8])+(matriz1[4]*matriz2[9])  +(matriz1[8]*matriz2[10]) +(matriz1[12]*matriz2[11]);
      matrizr[9]  = (matriz1[1]*matriz2[8])+(matriz1[5]*matriz2[9])  +(matriz1[9]*matriz2[10]) +(matriz1[13]*matriz2[11]);
      matrizr[10] = (matriz1[2]*matriz2[8])+(matriz1[6]*matriz2[9])  +(matriz1[10]*matriz2[10])+(matriz1[14]*matriz2[11]);
      matrizr[11] = (matriz1[3]*matriz2[8])+(matriz1[7]*matriz2[9])  +(matriz1[11]*matriz2[10])+(matriz1[15]*matriz2[11]);

      matrizr[12] = (matriz1[0]*matriz2[12])+(matriz1[4]*matriz2[13])+(matriz1[8]*matriz2[14]) +(matriz1[12]*matriz2[15]);
      matrizr[13] = (matriz1[1]*matriz2[12])+(matriz1[5]*matriz2[13])+(matriz1[9]*matriz2[14]) +(matriz1[13]*matriz2[15]);
      matrizr[14] = (matriz1[2]*matriz2[12])+(matriz1[6]*matriz2[13])+(matriz1[10]*matriz2[14])+(matriz1[14]*matriz2[15]);
      matrizr[15] = (matriz1[3]*matriz2[12])+(matriz1[7]*matriz2[13])+(matriz1[11]*matriz2[14])+(matriz1[15]*matriz2[15]);
    }


    int main(){
      int i;
      double tiempo1;
      double tiempo2;

      glfwInit();

      float *mat0 = NULL;
      float *mat1 = NULL;
      float *mat2 = NULL;

      mat0  = (float *)malloc(16 * sizeof(float));
      mat1  = (float *)malloc(16 * sizeof(float));
      mat2  = (float *)malloc(16 * sizeof(float));

      mat0[0]  =  1.0;
      mat0[1]  =  0.0;
      mat0[2]  =  0.0;
      mat0[3]  =  0.0;
      mat0[4]  =  0.0;
      mat0[5]  =  1.0;
      mat0[6]  =  0.0;
      mat0[7]  =  0.0;
      mat0[8]  =  0.0;
      mat0[9]  =  0.0;
      mat0[10] =  1.0;
      mat0[11] =  0.0;
      mat0[12] =  3.281897;
      mat0[13] =  4.714289;
      mat0[14] =  5.124306;
      mat0[15] =  1.0;

      mat1[0]  =  1.0;
      mat1[1]  =  0.0;
      mat1[2]  =  0.0;
      mat1[3]  =  0.0;
      mat1[4]  =  0.0;
      mat1[5]  =  0.924752;
      mat1[6]  =  0.380570;
      mat1[7]  =  0.0;
      mat1[8]  =  0.0;
      mat1[9]  = -0.380570;
      mat1[10] =  0.924752;
      mat1[11] =  0.0;
      mat1[12] =  0.0;
      mat1[13] =  0.0;
      mat1[14] =  0.0;
      mat1[15] =  1.0;

      mat2[0]  =  1.0;
      mat2[1]  =  0.0;
      mat2[2]  =  0.0;
      mat2[3]  =  0.0;
      mat2[4]  =  0.0;
      mat2[5]  =  1.0;
      mat2[6]  =  0.0;
      mat2[7]  =  0.0;
      mat2[8]  =  0.0;
      mat2[9]  =  0.0;
      mat2[10] =  1.0;
      mat2[11] =  0.0;
      mat2[12] =  0.0;
      mat2[13] =  0.0;
      mat2[14] =  0.0;
      mat2[15] =  1.0;

       tiempo1 = glfwGetTime();

       for(i=0;i<100000;i++){
        matriz_matriz(mat0,mat1,mat2);
        //cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor,CblasNoTrans,CblasNoTrans,4,4,4,1.0f,mat0,4,mat1,4,0.0f,mat2,4);
       }

      tiempo2 = glfwGetTime();
      printf("Tiempo total: %f\n",tiempo2-tiempo1);

      for(i=0;i<16;i++)printf("valor[%i]: %f\n",i,mat2[i]);

      free(mat0);
      free(mat1);
      free(mat2);

      system("pause");

      glfwTerminate();
      return 0;
    }
```

If I use the function cblas_sgemm (...) tiemp2 - tiempo1 variable returns the value of 0.096924, but if I use my own function (matriz_matriz(...)) tiempo2 - tiempo1 returns the value of 0.046271...What happens? My function is faster than Cblas...

This test was tested on a PC with Pentium 3 processor. Can anyone tell me what happens?

Thank you very much.

Comment: White kind of multiplication ? Element-wise ? Or an actual matrix multiplication ?

Comment: The result of matrix1[16] times matrix2[16] is a number or a matrix3[16][16], which one do you want?

Comment: That should be the same as two-dimensional arrays because arrays are stored row-wise in memory.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252621/matrix-multiplication-using-1d-arrays) is the code

Comment: matrix3[0] = matrix1[0]*matrix2[0] + matrix1[4]*matrix2[1] + matrix1[8]*matrix2[2] + matrix1[12]*matrix2[3]; matrix3[1] = ... etc.

Comment: Can you try explaining more clearly what it is you are trying to accomplish? Perhaps with a more thourough example. What you're saying makes no sense.

Mathwise, A matrix is a multidimenstional construct composed of multiple vectors. A vector is a 1D collection of numbers...

It sounds like you are asking about vector dot product or vector cross product? Or perhaps just vectorizing a bunch of scalar multiplications through a matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, if you're doing any kind of linear algebra, by far your best bet is to use libraries designed for the purpose, such as *BLAS*, *LAPACK*, etc. You will have a very hard time approaching their speed with your own code.

Matrix-matrix operations are BLAS Level 3, and the particular one you want is `SGEMM()` for `float`s and `DGEMM()` for `double`s. The fastest BLAS implementation on Intel hardware are *OpenBLAS* (derived from GotoBLAS) and the BLAS implementation in Intel's *MKL* (math kernel library). *ATLAS* is also very fast if you compile it yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much friend for you answer. :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Incidentally, if all you want to do is multiply two matrices (C=A*B) that are *always* 4x4 and never any other size, and you don't want to get into BLAS, your best bet is to transpose the B matrix, and use intrinsics to do a SIMD (SSE/AVX) multiply followed by a horizontal sum for each element of C.

Answer (score 0):

A version for 2 x 2 matrix (based on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252621/matrix-multiplication-using-1d-arrays)):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int rows = 2;
    const int cols = 2;

    float a[4]={1,2,3,4};
    float b[4]={1,2,3,4};
    float c[4]={0,0,0,0};

    for (int i = 0; i <rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <cols; j++) 
        {   
            float sum = 0.0;
            for (int k = 0; k < rows; k++)
                sum = sum + a[i * cols + k] * b[k * cols + j]; 
            c[i * cols + j] = sum;
        }   
    }   
    for (int ix =0; ix <4; ++ix)
            cout << c[ix] << ' ';

}
```

Comment: This is the fastest way?

Comment: @JavierRamírez: no, the naïve algorithm with i-j-k loop-ordering is known to have the worst possible cache behavior for large matrices. For these tiny matrices, the loop ordering probably doesn't matter.  The Intel and Sun compilers will spot this “anti-pattern” and do the loop interchange necessary to get good performance, but gcc didn't do this the last time I checked.